# Trying to download an xml file to my local from an Azure Storage Container- opens a page that shows the xml instead

Tags: azure-storage, azureportal

I'm trying to download an xml file to my local, for some testing I'd like to do, from a Storage Container using Azure Portal- Although it just opens a webpage where it shows the xml rather than downloading it to my local.

For whatever reason some xml files do this, and some download as expected. Why is this happening?

Comment: Check the content-type property of the blob. The ones that are downloaded should have the value like application/octet-stream.

Comment: @GauravMantri Just checked- all have "text/xml" as their content type. Downloadable ones and ones that don't download

Comment: @GauravMantri odd, I've just fixed it. I clicked the download button that I found inside of the properties tab and it downloaded normally.

Answer (score 0):

> Trying to download an xml file to my local from an Azure Storage Container- opens a page that shows the xml instead

I do agree that you can download a file using Download option in properties tab as clearly visible as below:

[image]

After Downloading you can open as you want in Local:

[image]